# Changing column constraint null/not null = rowguid replication error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, constraints, ssms, merge-replication

I have a database running under Sql server 2005 with merge replication. I want to change some of the FK columns to be 'not null' as they should always have a value. SQL server won't let me do that though, this is what it says:

> - Unable to modify table.   It is invalid to drop the default constraint
>     on the rowguid column that is used by
>     merge replication. The schema change
>     failed during execution of an internal
>     replication procedure. For corrective
>     action, see the other error messages
>     that accompany this error message. The
>     transaction ended in the trigger. The
>     batch has been aborted.

I am not trying to change the constraints on the rowguid column at all, only on another column that is acting as a FK. Other columns I want to set to be not null because the record doesn't make any sense without that information (i.e. on a customer, the customer name).

Questions: 
Is there a way to update columns to be 'not null' without turning off replication then turning it back on again? 
Is this even the best way to do this - should I be using a constraint instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently SSMS makes changes to tables by dropping them and recreating them. So just needed to make the changes using T-SQL statement.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to script out your change in T-SQL statements as SQL Server Management Studio will look to drop and re-create the table, as opposed to simply adding the additional column.

You will also need to add the new column to your Publications.

Please note that changing a column in this manner can be detrimental to the performance  of Replication. Dependent on the size of the table you are altering, can lead to a lot of data being replicated. Consider that although your table modification can be performed in a single statement, if 1 million rows are affected then 1 million updates will be generated at the Subscriber, NOT a single update statement as is commonly thought.

The hands on, improved performance approach.......

To perform this exercise you need to:

1. Backup your Replication environment by scripting out your entire configuration.
2. Remove the table from Replication at
   both Publishers/Subscribers
3. Add the column at each
   Publisher/Subscriber.
4. Apply the Update locally at each
   Publisher/Subscriber.
5. Add the table back into Replication.
6. Validate that transactions are being
   Replicated.